# Invoke-Command Powershell - error: Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null and expression after character in pipeline

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the Invoke-Command to login to remote server and set to a location path and execute few commands. I am reading the data from a configuration xml in the powershell.
My xml is of below type

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Config>   
  <Action Name="Deploy">
            <CommandPath>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Sql server\110\</CommandPath>            
            <DeploymentServer>
                <Server Name = 'Server1'></Server>
                <Server Name = 'Server2'></Server>  
            </DeploymentServer>
            <Deployscript1 Name = 'listservices' > </Deployscript1>
            <Deployscript2 Name = 'script2' > </Deployscript2>
  </Action>
  <Action Name="Update">
    //few more nodes
  </Action>     
</Config>
```

I have tried the below powershell.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

function RunConfiguration()
{

# get an array of 'Action' XmlElements
$actionNodes = (Select-Xml -Path $configFile -XPath '//Action').Node

do {
    $Answer = Read-Host -Prompt "Select required action '$($actionNodes.Name -join "', '")'"
} Until ($Answer -in ($actionNodes.Name))

$selectedNode = $actionNodes | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $Answer}
Write-Host $selectedNode.Name

$selectedNode.DeploymentServer.Server | ForEach-Object {
    $ServerName = $_.Name
    Write-Host $ServerName
    
if($selectedNode.Name -ieq "deploy")
{
$ScriptCode  = $selectedNode.Deployscript1.Name
$ScriptCode2  = $selectedNode.Deployscript2.Name
}
Write-Host $ScriptCode
Write-Host $selectedNode.CommandPath

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -ScriptBlock {
 $Configuration = $args[0]
 Set-Location $selectedNode.CommandPath

#Execute first command       
        & $ScriptCode

#Execute second command
        $ScriptCode2
    } -ArgumentList $SelectedAnswer
  }
}


$spAdminServiceName = "SPAdminV4"
$currentDir=(split-path $myinvocation.mycommand.path -parent)
$configFile = $currentDir
$configFile += "\DeployConfig.xml"
Execute-Commands $configFile

RunConfiguration

Write-Host -f White "Press Enter key to exit..."
Read-Host
```

I am getting the below 2 errors:
Error 1: Cannot process argument because the value of argument "path" is null. Change the value of argument "path" to a non-null value.

Error 2: The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.

I am able to get correct path which is there in xml in the write host for the path. How to fix these 2 errors?
Thanks

Updated Code 1: I am able to get the values from XML without any issues.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -ScriptBlock {
        $Configuration = $args[0]
  
#Navigate to location
        Set-Location $scriptPath.ToString()

#Execute first command

        & $ScriptCode

#Execute second command

        $ScriptCode1    
    } -ArgumentList $SelectedAnswer
```

Answer (score 0):

#1 - You dont appear to be defining `$configFile`?

```
$actionNodes = (Select-Xml -Path $configFile -XPath '//Action').Node
```

Try adding `Write-Host "Config file is: $($configFile)";` at the start of `RunConfiguration()` function - is it the correct value? Is $configFile supposed to be passed as an argument or declared globally - your function currently does not accept any parameters?

#2 - The $ScriptCode variable is going to be an object, it needs to be a string. Check the type of a variable like this:

```
$ScriptCode.GetType()
```

When your calling `Write-Host $ScriptCode` what powershell is actually running is probably `Write-Host $ScriptCode.ToString()` - which returns just the correct text. When you pass that variable with the call operator `&` your passing the entire object not just the filename. You need to convert `$ScriptCode` to be a string first:

Try either (sorry, untested code):

```
& ([string] $ScriptCode)
```

or

```
& $ScriptCode.ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the scriptcode with ToString(). I am getting the below errors now. Error 1 : You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Error 2 : The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
  Note: Updated my latest code in the first post

Comment: The variables `$ScriptCode` and `$ScriptCode1` will have the same problem as `$scriptPath` - they are all objects not strings (because thats what `Select-Xml` returns when you read in your file).

Comment: I have added ToString to all of them . I still get the same error - You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. Is the way I am doing correct for Invoke-Command

Comment: The error is telling you `$ScriptCode` is null - there is no value - so you cant `Invoke-Command` with an empty variable (and you cant call `.ToString()` on it either because null is not an object, its what powershell uses to describe something having no value). You need to work through your code like i described in my answer using lines like `Write-Host $ScriptCode` and `Write-Host $ScriptCode.GetType()` in different places to see whats going on at each stage in your script. You might want to read-up on using a debugger and breakpoints with powershell to inspect your code during execution too